# How to delay a method/animation?

Tags: ios, uilabel, nsdate, nsthread

so I have a simple animation in my view. It just swoops a bunch of UILabels from the top right hand side of the screen to their set coordinates. I would like a slight delay between each label though so they trickle out one by one. Right now it's just too fast:

```
-(void)drawLabels
{


for(int i=0; i<[self.onScreenLabels count]; i++)
{
    UILabel *label = self.onScreenLabels[i];

    int x = label.frame.origin.x;
    int y= label.frame.origin.y;

    label.center=CGPointMake(320, 0);
    [self.view addSubview:label];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        label.center=CGPointMake(x, y);


    }];

    NSDate *future = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow: 0.5 ];
    [NSThread sleepUntilDate:future];



}

}
```

I would like to have a delay after drawing each label on screen, you an see above I have tried to use NSDate and NSThread however it doesn't seem to make any difference. Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach using animateWithDuration:delay:

```
CGFloat delay = 0.0f;

for(int i=0; i<[self.onScreenLabels count]; i++)
{
    UILabel *label = self.onScreenLabels[i];

    int x = label.frame.origin.x;
    int y = label.frame.origin.y;

    label.center=CGPointMake(320, 0);
    [self.view addSubview:label];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 delay:delay options:0 animations:^{

        label.center=CGPointMake(x, y);

    } completion:^(BOOL finished){

    }];

    delay += 0.5f;                  // add 1/2 second delay to each label (0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5)

}
```

Comment: it works if I increment the delay like you wrote above, however if I use a constant value such as 2.0f there is no delay at all. Why is this? Is there a way to keep the delay constant?

Comment: if you have 5 labels, you're kicking off 5 animations at once, at delays of 0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5, 2.0 seconds.  If you set the delay to a constant, then all will kick off at the same time.  The delay is the time it waits to BEGIN the animation for that particular label.

Comment: why do all the animations kick off at the same time if it is iterating though the array and then animating?

Comment: what I'm asking is, is it possible for each animation to wait one second before kicking off? i.e. for 5 labels 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0 not kicking off at the same time

Comment: delay += 1.0f; will run the animations at one second intervals

Answer (score 2):

How bout this

```
[self performSelector:@selector(moveLabel) withObject:label afterDelay:0.5];
```

Comment: I tired this, I take the loop out of the method but loop through the array in viewDidLoad instead, passing an instance of UILabel to animate. No luck though.

Comment: My guess is that your'e forgetting the colon `@selector(moveLabel:)` that indicates that there will be a parameter in your moveLabel method.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `NSTimer` class. An example:

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.5
target:self
selector:@selector(drawLabels)
userInfo:nil
repeats:YES];
```

This will create a timer that will fire each 0.5 seconds in this class calling *drawLabels* method. You may want to edit your method as well

Comment: won't that affect the loop in an odd way though? surely it will draw some labels, delay 0.5 seconds then call drawLabels again thus starting the loop again

Comment: @Kex that's why I added *You may want to edit your method as well*